# How to make weapon 'bullet' go a certain direction

Tags: javascript, html, sprite, game-physics, sprite-sheet

I am trying to make a 'bullet' from the *var weapon* shoot in a certain direction, this bullet is actually a pokemon ball as I am just making a practice game.

I cannot seem to make the 'bullet' go in the direction that I would like it to, I entered: `weapon.body.velocity.x = -100;` under the: `if (cursors.left.isDown)` 
but this did not work, when I pressed any key the screen would just freeze.

Please help me make the 'bullet' go in the direction I want.

```js
var items;
var game;
var player;
var weapon;
var cursors;
var fireButton;


function addItems() {
  items = game.add.physicsGroup();
  createItem(100, 400, 'coin');
}

function createItem(left, top, image) {
  var item = items.create(left, top, image);
  item.animations.add('spin');
  item.animations.play('spin', 10, true);
}

function itemHandler(player, item) {
  item.kill();

}


window.onload = function () {
  game = new Phaser.Game(800, 600, Phaser.CANVAS, 'phaser-example', { preload: preload, create: create, update: update, render: render });

  function preload() {

    game.stage.backgroundColor = ('#424242');

    game.load.spritesheet('coin', 'coin.png', 36, 44);
    game.load.spritesheet('player', 'hero.png', 64, 64);
    game.load.spritesheet('bullet', 'Pokeball.png');


  }


  function create() {

        player = this.game.add.sprite(100, 200, 'player');
    // ANIMATION FOR PLAYER CONTROLS
        down = player.animations.add('down', [0,1,2,3], 10, true);
        left = player.animations.add('left', [4,5,6,7], 10, true);
        right = player.animations.add('right', [8,9,10,11], 10, true);
        up = player.animations.add('up', [12,13,14,15], 10, true);

        // enable physics in the game (can't go through walls, gravity, etc.)

        game.physics.enable(player, Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
        game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.P2JS);
        game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
        game.physics.p2.enable(player);


        player.body.setSize(30, 45, 16, 12);
        player.body.immovable = false;
        // enable keyboard arrows for controls
        cursors = game.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();
        // camera will follow the character
        game.camera.follow(player);

        addItems();


        //  Creates 1 single bullet, using the 'bullet' graphic
        weapon = game.add.weapon(1, 'bullet');

        //  The bullet will be automatically killed when it leaves the world bounds
        weapon.bulletKillType = Phaser.Weapon.KILL_WORLD_BOUNDS;

        //  Because our bullet is drawn facing up, we need to offset its rotation:


        //  The speed at which the bullet is fired
        weapon.bulletSpeed = 400;



        game.physics.arcade.enable(player);

        //  Tell the Weapon to track the 'player' Sprite, offset by 14px horizontally, 0 vertically
        weapon.trackSprite(player, 30, 0);

        cursors = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();

        fireButton = this.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.KeyCode.SPACEBAR);

  }

  function update() {

        game.physics.arcade.overlap(player, items, itemHandler);

    // PLAYER CONTROLS
        player.body.velocity.set(0);
        // player presses left key
        if (cursors.left.isDown)
        {
            player.body.velocity.x = -100;
            player.play('left');
        }
        // player presses right key
        else if (cursors.right.isDown)
        {
            player.body.velocity.x = 100;
            player.play('right');
        }
        // player presses up key
        else if (cursors.up.isDown)
        {
            player.body.velocity.y = -100;
            player.play('up');
        }
        // player presses down key
        else if (cursors.down.isDown)
        {
            player.body.velocity.y = 100;
            player.play('down');
        }
        // player does not press anything
        else
        {
            player.animations.stop();
        }

        if (fireButton.isDown)
        {
          weapon.fire();
        }

  }

  function render() {

    weapon.debug();

  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/phaser/3.18.1/phaser.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Simple Canvas Game</title>
    <style>
      html {
        background: black
      }
      canvas {
        margin: auto;
      }
    </style>
 </head>
 <body>
    <script src="phaser.js"></script>
  <script src="game.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: try this; weapon.body.velocity.x -= 100;

Comment: @KrisJ. It still freezes when I click any key.

Comment: dont you get any error?

Comment: it doesn't show any errors @KrisJ.

Comment: It  shoots great, but only in one direction, when I put that code in, it freezes

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
weapon.trackSprite(player, 30, 0);
```

to

```
weapon.trackSprite(player, 30, 0, true);
```

Phaser's documentation says that if you pass true as the fourth parameter, then it will follow the sprite's rotation.

Edit: You're not currently doing any rotation to your sprite, so change the angle where you are checking for player changing the sprite's direction:

```
    if (cursors.left.isDown)
    {
        player.angle = 180;
    }
    else if (cursors.right.isDown)
    {
        player.angle = -90;
    }
    else if (cursors.up.isDown)
    {
        player.angle = 90;
    }
    // player presses down key
    else if (cursors.down.isDown)
    {
        player.angle = 0;
    }
```

This will also rotate your player sprite, so maybe this isn't what you want.

Comment: I edited my answer to address that. I think the bullets track your sprite's rotation, so if you rotate the sprite when the player presses the arrow keys it should work, or at least get you going in the right direction.

Comment: this works, except I don't want my player to be flipped upside down and around haha, is there a way I can rotate the bounds of the sprite rather than the image itself? this way maybe the bullet would listen to the rotation of the bound of the sprite being rotated, but the image would stay the same? @VasilyKushakov